# Calculate the product of $p(x)q(x) \pmod{x^3 +1}$

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I need to calculate the product of $(x^2 + 3x + 1)(x^2 + 4x + 3)\pmod{x^3 + 1}$, where the product is in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Is this problem as simple as just multiplying the two, which would be $4x^4 + 7x^3 +16x^2 + 9x + 3$, and then dividing $x^3 + 1$ into it?

Comment: Yes, though note that you can also reduce the coefficients mod $5$ before you divide. The product is the remainder after division by $x^{3}+1$.

Comment: That should be $x^4 + \ldots + 13 x + \ldots$.

Comment: Thanks.But do you mean by "reduce the coefficients by mod 5"?